# Row added twice to table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a table with jquery. My code is like this:

```
function showGrid(url, container, columns, page) {
    jQuery(container).empty();

    var tr = jQuery("<tr class=\"mobileGridHeader\"><tr>");

    var tdTotalRows = jQuery("<td>test</td>");
    jQuery(tr).append(tdTotalRows);

    var table = jQuery('<table class="mobileGrid"></table>');
    jQuery(table).append(tr);

    jQuery(container).append(table);
}
```

The container is a div on the page. The problem is, that the tr is added twice to the container and I do not know why.

[image]

It is not just a Browser error, in the Html I can see the code twice.

```
<table class="mobileGrid">
   <tbody>
       <tr class="mobileGridHeader">
           <td>test</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>test</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The weird is also, that the css class "mobileGridHeader" is only added in the first row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not close `tr` tag in your creation so 2 elements are created. To fix the issue instead of this line:

```
var tr = jQuery("<tr class=\"mobileGridHeader\"><tr>");
```

use this line (backslash added):

```
var tr = jQuery("<tr class=\"mobileGridHeader\"></tr>");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you haven't closed off your tr tag:

```
var tr = jQuery("<tr class=\"mobileGridHeader\"><tr>");
                                                ^^^^
```

Needs to be:

```
var tr = jQuery("<tr class=\"mobileGridHeader\"></tr>");
```

Or even:

```
var tr = jQuery("<tr class=\"mobileGridHeader\">");
```

Otherwise jQuery will auto-close both `tr` tags, creating two rows.

Comment: Thx, what a stupid mistake! I accepted dotnetom because he was a little bit earlier.